# Is there a way to make embed fetch a required subset of a PDF instead of downloading it all at once?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, embed

I have a large pdf in an embed tag, it gets downloaded in full on each page load.

Is there a way to make it download only the required pdf range - first page first, next pages when scrolling?

If not, is there a way to embed a pdf to an HTML page and make it download only the required pages?

If not, what would be the best approach to showing only the required PDF pages when needed, like converting pages to images, and fetching images with js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can't with any degree of consistency. A web-optimized PDF, also known as a linearized PDF, with a conforming reader like the Adobe Reader will do this automatically. However, most of the modern browsers will use their own built-in PDF viewer and you're at their mercy when it comes to loading the file.

Rather than convert the PDF to images, what you could do is use the object tag rather than embed but don't set the data attribute to the PDF. Instead, fetch the PDF via AJAX (or something) and once the file is downloaded, then set the data attribute. The PDF should only download once using that method.